# Fail JSON parameters in the call to the web service post

Tags: json, rest, jquery, resteasy

Implementing a web service RestEasy rest, I have a problem.

Ajax Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var sUrlBusqueda = "http://localhost:8888/rest/posiciones/testPost";

        var valores = new Object();
        valores.lat = '12';
        valores.lng = '12';
        valores.radio = '12';

        var parametros = new Array();
        parametros[0] = "lat";
        parametros[1] = "lng";
        parametros[2] = "radio";

        var jsonText = JSON.stringify(valores, parametros, "\t");


          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              url: sUrlBusqueda,
              data: jsonText,
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (data) {//On Successfull service call
                    var sCadena = "";

                    $.each(data, function(i,data){
                        sCadena = sCadena + data.oCoordenadaVO.id;
                    });
                    alert(sCadena);
                },
              failure: function ServiceFailed(data) {
                    alert('error');

                    return;
                }
          }); 
          });
```

Web service:

```
 @Override
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public List<CoordenadaVO> getLocalizacionesPost(
        @DefaultValue("0") @QueryParam("lat") String lat,
        @DefaultValue("0") @QueryParam("lng") String lng,
        @DefaultValue("0") @QueryParam("radio") String radio) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     }
```

In the web service I receive only value parameters to the default value 0. This is the Json code shipping, I do not see the error any ideas?.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
@Override
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public List<CoordenadaVO> getLocalizacionesPost(
        ConfigBusquedaVO config) {}

public class ConfigBusquedaVO {

    private String lat = "";

    private String lng = "";

    private String radio = "";

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public String getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(String lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public String getRadio() {
        return radio;
    }

    public void setRadio(String radio) {
        this.radio = radio;
    }


}
```